# Pop up message not await for user response and moving on on onclick function

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have this logic on changing radio-button selection, if the user made some changing I am showing a message. if he confirm it will enter Onconfirm, else - Onreject.

**1 issue ->** the change of the radio button happens before the message show.

**2 issue ->** one reject I want to cancel the choice he made and to undo to his last choise - whice not happenning.

**please help me with this!!**

radio button

```
  <div class="right" *ngFor="let type of types">
    <p-radioButton  name="treesDetailsType"  [(ngModel)]="oneselectedType" formControlName="selectedType" (onClick)="onChangeType(type,$event)" class="treeDetails" value="{{type.id}}" label="{{type.desc}}" [disabled]="isReadOnly && type.id != data.selectedType"></p-radioButton>
  </div>
```

the function of onclick

```
  onChangeType(type, $event) {
    let isFormTouched = this.isFormTouched(type);

    
    if (isFormTouched) {
    this.messagingService.showConfirmById(44, () => {
      this.onConfirm()
  }, () => {
        this.onReject($event);
      
    });


}
else
   this.onchangedTrue(type); //this set some validators for the choice

}
```

on reject

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) onReject($event) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //whatever written here its not happens before the change !!!!!
    console.log(event);
  }
```

----edited after the perfect suggestion from @Eliseo

```
 askConfirm(value: any) {
    let isFormTouched = this.isFormTouched(value);

    if (isFormTouched) {
      this.messagingService.showConfirmById(44, () => {
        this.oneselectedType = value;
        this.fg.controls.selectedType.setValue(value);
      }, () => {
        this.radios.forEach(x => {
          x.writeValue(this.oneselectedType);
        })
       

      },
      );


    }
    else {
      this.oneselectedType = value;
      this.onchangedTrue(value);
  }



  }`
```

the code work perfectly without the condition
--edited - on get the value from the server and patch it - the radio button lost
[image: 2 is fron the formGroup]

Comment: In most cases, you shouldn't be using async/await/promises in a Angular application. I strongly recommend you to stick with RxJS/Observables.

Comment: What Allan said and additionally- you don’t want to combine ngModel and formControlName - those do not go well together..

Comment: @AllanJuan ok thank tou, can you give example with what I need ths way?

Comment: @AllanJuan I ermoved the async/await/promises  , changed the ngmodel name, and the behevior is the same, the message show after the change of radio button

Comment: @MikeOne I changed and still

Comment: @MikeOne I spending days for solving it, maybe it some bug of primeng that the event fires before the logic in the onclick function?

Comment: @AllanJuan what do you think?

Comment: Edit the post with the updated version of your code so we can help.

Comment: @AllanJuan Done. many thanks!!

Comment: Just too many questions and not enough code. Where does ‘type’ come from? Why are you not simply using your reactive form to find out if the value changed? This seems completely overkill for what you need, but again, not enough code to determine what the issue is. Maybe you can create a simplified stackblitz?

Comment: @MikeOne I edited again. type is from list of Items I got from the server, this is the issue that the data come from the server I can't make stackblitz. but the issue is what happens from the simple code, it will happen in every code on stackblitz that the radio button of primeng change before anything you want, and you can't catch the event.

Comment: how can I delay the change of the choice until the `showConfirmById` finished with onconfirm\onreject? and how can I cancel the choice on onreject? @MikeOne

Comment: @AllanJuan I edited again

Comment: You have the form control on which you can listen to valueChanges. In there you can run your conditions and if needed set the checkbox to unchecked again if needed?

Comment: @MikeOne `this.fg.controls.selectedType.setValue(this.oneselectedType);` this way? I tried to do it with valueChanges but didn't work, maybe I should do it diffrently?

Comment: can it be inside the onclick? @MikeOne

Comment: **never** mix ngModel and formControlName

Comment: @Eliseo so what you suggest for this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3406 Similar issue

Comment: @MikeOne anywat the solution there did not woek

Comment: @YoelPerkal, it's only split the [(ngModel)] in [ngModel] and (ngModelChanged). I wrote an answer. I can not check and I'm not prety sure if it's neccesary use a temporal variable called ,e.g. `possibleValue` and at first in askConfirm you use `this.possibleValue=value` and in acept use `this.selectedType=this.possibleValue`. Sorry my bad comment, really I've went to anothers SO that mix ngModel and formControlName (Programming is think fisrt and write after)

Comment: @Eliseo hi, question about youe solution, on readonly state, when the user choosed already radio button I want only to show is choice, but it gone, why?

Comment: @Eliseo if Im changing it to `[value]="isReadOnly ? fg.get('selectedType').value : type" ` it work fine

Comment: @Eliseo in the why I wrote it if he picked 3 `fg.get('selectedType').value` = 3 the forth radio button  look like choosed in readonly situation, you have an idea why? thanksss

Comment: To give a value to a formControl **not** use value=.., You shoud use "setValue": `fg.get('selectedType').setValue(3)`

Comment: @Eliseo that for sure. what I wrote it the html - the value of the radio button according to  `selectedType`

Comment: @Eliseo what I need is the by default the radios in your solution will have the selected value from the form group

Comment: when you create the formGroup you can give value to the formControls, or you can use patchValue (I update again the stackblitz adding comments)

Comment: I don't know how create a chat (I think that it's only you click the link:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238520/about-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69666599 if you has a time

Comment: I added it but not wirking yet. maybe because your solution is that for every click he will enter ask3/ask2 function. but what if he wont? if I need default value for `selectedCity`? if he didnt choose \ choose already and the data is from the server not from the function, how the radio button will be on this choice? thank you so much

Comment: @Eliseo I dont know why I cant answer in the room, I understand what you say, I have the value and I patched the value. but the radios dont get the default in it        ` <p-radioButton #radio name="type" [value]="isReadOnly ? fg.get('selectedType').value : type" (ngModelChange)="askConfirm($event,radios)" [ngModel]="fg.get('selectedType').value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" value="{{type.id}}" label="{{type.desc}}" [disabled]="isReadOnly " class="treeDetails p-field-radiobutton"></p-radioButton>`

Comment: The default value is the value you give in the formGroup

Comment: @Eliseo in the formGroup I have the value I need

Comment: my good!! I just find the problem in the code, see that in the radiobuttons of colors I've use `<p-radioButton  #radioColor...>` and the name of variable of the QueryList was the same, so Angular give an error in console. The soution, just corrected in code is use `<p-radioButton  #radioColor...(ngModelChange)="ask3($event,'selectedColor',radiosColor)">` -see that I use radio**s** and the ViewChildren `@ViewChildren('radioColor', { read: RadioButton }) radiosColor!: QueryList<RadioButton>`

Comment: @Eliseo thank you so much, but this is not the issue in my code, see in the picture I edited the post, after I got the value from the server, which is 2 in, the radio botton not on two selection

Comment: @Eliseo after write it `        <p-radioButton #radio name="type" [value]="isReadOnly ? oneselectedType : type" (ngModelChange)="askConfirm($event,radios)" [ngModel]="fg.get('selectedType').value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" value="{{type.id}}" label="{{type.desc}}" [disabled]="isReadOnly " class="treeDetails p-field-radiobutton"></p-radioButton>` it shows me the radio but instead of 3-> become 4!! I'm lost man

Comment: @Eliseo again about your solution, can I use it with RadioButtonModule ? it not have writeValue. the grafhic cahnged a little bit, I want the radio button to stay agter click in the page

Comment: Yoel, sorry the delay and the loose time. I make another answer with a new stackblitz and another solutions. Really I thought that only call to writeValue could work. I make a work-around, but a more simple idea is get the old value, change the radio button, and if we don't want the value set the old value (In the stackblitz you has the two solutions -the more simple is wich use "form2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a problem in my code (the another answer). Really I'm not pretty sure the reason, so I create a function like

```
  redraw()
  {
    const value = this.form.value.type;
    this.radios.forEach((x) => {
      x.writeValue(value)
    });
  }
```

So, my function "ask" becomes like

```
  ask(value: any) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Do you want to choose ' + value + '?',
      header: 'Choose Confirmation',
      icon: 'pi pi-info-circle',
      key: 'positionDialog',
      accept: () => {
        this.form.get('type').setValue(value);
      },
      reject: () => {
        this.redraw()
      },
    });
  }
```

This allow me, when change the form, call to the function redraw. If I has a function

```
  getForm(data: any = null) {
    data = data || { type: 1, prop: '' };
    return new FormGroup({
      type: new FormControl(data.type),
      prop: new FormControl(data.prop),
    });
  }
```

I can do some like

```
  loadData(id: number) {
    this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.form = this.getForm(res);
      //it's necesary call to the function this.redraw
      this.redraw()
    });
  }
  newData() {
    this.form = this.getForm();
    //it's necesary call to the function this.redraw
    this.redraw()
  }
```

See in the [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xjrn1g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) what happens if we don't call to `this.redraw()` (just comment the lines)

1.-Select "new York" and say that you don't want it
2.-Click the button to load user

As "user" has the type 3 -"new York", the radio buttons looks like that it's not selected.

Yes is an ugly work-around, but for now I can not imagine another solution

Well there're another approach, that is change the value as usually and if we say that we want not the value, return the old value

```
  askAfterChange(value:any)
  {
    const oldValue=this.form2.value.type;
    this.form2.get('type').setValue(value)
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Do you want to choose ' + value + '?',
      header: 'Choose Confirmation',
      icon: 'pi pi-info-circle',
      key: 'positionDialog',
      accept: () => {
      },
      reject: () => {
        this.form2.get('type').setValue(oldValue);
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440294/p-multiselect-onchange-prevent-adding-elements-with-the-same-index maybe you can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The "key" is split the [(ngModel)] in [ngModel] and (ngModelChanged)

```
//NOT WORK yet
<p-radioButton ... [ngModel]="selectedType"
             (ngModelChange)="askConfirm($event)">

askConfirm(value: any) {

    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure do you want '+value+'?',
        header: 'Delete Confirmation',
        icon: 'pi pi-info-circle',
        accept: () => {
            this.selectedType=value
        },
        reject: () => {
        },
        key: "positionDialog"
    });
}
```

Well the problem is that the element still show the value selected How resolved? The first is get our p-radio buttons using ViewChildren, so we are give a template reference variable (the same to all the buttons) see the `#radio`

```
    <div *ngFor="let type  of types" class="p-field-radiobutton">
        <p-radioButton #radio ... 
           (ngModelChange)="ask($event)" 
           [ngModel]="oneselectedType" ></p-radioButton>
    </div>

  //get the "radio buttons"
  @ViewChildren('radio', { read: RadioButton }) radios!: QueryList<RadioButton>

  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { }

  ask(value: any) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Do you want to choose this?',
      header: 'Choose Confirmation',
      icon: 'pi pi-info-circle',
      key: 'positionDialog',
      accept: () => {
        //if accept
        this.oneselectedType = value
      },
      reject: () => {
        //else, we loop over all the "radios"
        this.radios.forEach(x => {
          //and force is checked
          x.writeValue(this.oneselectedType);
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

If you're using reactive Forms, you can also use a [ngModel] (ngModelChange) in the way, see that the model is `myForm.get('selectedType').value`

```
<p-radioButton ... [ngModel]="myForm.get('selectedType').value"
             (ngModelChanged)="askConfirm($event)"
             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
 >
```

And change in askConfirm

```
askConfirm(value: any) {

    this.confirmationService.confirm({
        ...
        accept: () => {
            this.form.get('oneselectedType').setValue(value)
        },
        reject: () => {
        this.radios.forEach(x => {
          //and force is checked
          x.writeValue(this.form.value.oneselectedType);
        })
        },
        key: "positionDialog"
    });
}
```

a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-khksft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Well, In the stackblitz I hard-code the value of the formGroup. Generally we has a service so we can
1.-Define our Form

```
  form=new FormGroup({
    selectedCity:new FormControl(),
    selectedColor:new FormControl(),
    prop:new FormControl()
  })

//And in ngOnInit

this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res=>{
  this.form.patchValue(res)
})
```

Or 2.-simple declare our form

```
form:FormGroup

//and in ngOnInit
```

use in ngOnInit

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res=>{
  this.form=new FormGroup({
    selectedCity:new FormControl(res.selectedCity),
    selectedColor:new FormControl(res.selectedColor),
    prop:new FormControl(res.prop)
  })

})
```

If we need a default value, we can give the value at first

(the stackblitz has in code this options)

Comment: thanks, for what is the key and ngModelOptions, and if it enter reject how it undo the change?

Comment: `ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'p-radioButton'`

Comment: ngModelOptions is to allow use [ngModel] inside a `<div [formGroup]="myFrom">`

Comment: thanks but I cant use it on primeng, also `(ngModelChanged)` not entering the function when I changed the button.  another suggestion for me please?

Comment: let me a momment to check and correct the code

Comment: @YoelPerkal, just do it :)

Comment: thank you so much!! one question before it will work perfectly, can't I add `formControlName="selectedType"`? I need it to bind to the final choice, because if the radio button is 1 - it will bind to a child component

Comment: I also added condition, that if some changes done only then it will bring the message - and do the logic you write, but then it does not work the same, its not changing the choise if he confirmed, why? I will add the code to my question, many thanks!!

Comment: Yoel, you needn't use formControlName="selectedType". If you see the stackblitz -I recently update, see now- the second example use a formGroup but change the formControl "selectedCity" using ngModel. A FormControl needn't has a input in .html, a FormControl -or a FormControl that belong to a FormGroup exist independtly the .html

Comment: Yoel, you should choose, or you mannage the value using a FormGroup -or a FormControl- or mannage the value using one variable, but not both, I don't know about your isFormTouched function NOTE: In the else you don't change the form control using setValue

Comment: ok thank you so much, I will see again, and maybe I need to read more about this way, didn't know if before(if you can send me to a website I will love it), I accept your answer and I would give you a real medal!! small dessert question, when I change the radio - button I have a blue border on a choice but after doing some randomaly clicks on the form (not on the radio button ) it disapear, how can I make it stay until I am changing my choice? and again big thank you!!

Comment: sure you right , I added it to the else statment

Comment: see that you need to have so many QueryList as "group of radio buttons" (a different template reference variable in each group). You can pass to the function "ask" the "field" and the "radios". Be carefull not use the same template reference variable. I update the stackblitz again -see the "ask3" function

Comment: Thank you very much, will check. Question about your design to open new question?

Comment: just to know, there is why to have the same behvior with formControlName Instead of ngmode? make the form control wait somehow? this is perfect just to learn. thanks