# p-multiSelect onchange prevent adding elements with the same index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, primeng

I have multiselect option with 6 options from array. one of the option is a bit diffrent then the others(it lets adding remark and in the others not). when I am selecting this option and one of the fields x(the remark), after I removing it and selecting again but the field will be null (lets say in the first case I am adding reark and in the second time I'm not) so the multi select will add it twice! but I want 1 velue for every index(without care of the other fields).**how should I do it?**  another place it different in getting the selected values from the server, when it should be selected after the user choosed it it seemes like he didn't choose.

```
  <p-multiSelect *ngIf="_decision.decisionStatusId == eDecisionType.Reject || _decision.decisionStatusId == eDecisionType.ReturnedToUser" [required]="formGroup.hasError('remark-reasons-required')"
                   [options]="reasons" defaultLabel="" formControlName="remarks" [(ngModel)]="selectedReasons" optionLabel="hebName"
                   [ngClass]="_decision.decisionStatusId == eDecisionType.ReturnedToUser || _decision.decisionStatusId == eDecisionType.Reject ? '' : 'display-none'"
                   selectedItemsLabel="{0} "
                   (onChange)="onChangeReasonsValue($event)"></p-multiSelect>
```

.ts

```
onChangeReasonsValue(event: { value: ReviewDecisionReasonModel[] }): void {
    this.selectedReasons = event.value;
    this._decision.reasons = event.value;
    this.formGroup.markAsDirty();
    this.formGroup.markAsTouched();
    this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

[same index values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPDfc.png)

Comment: Ylove, **remove** the `[(ngModel)]` (You can **not** use in the same tag `[ngModel]` and `formControlName`). Really I don't understand what do you want to do. A p-multiselect get as value an array with all the values selected. You needn't use `(onchange)`. Just use `{{form?.value|json}}` in the .html to check the value

Comment: @Eliseo thanks but in case of removing the selected I need to update my array value, without on change it wont happend perfectly. my probelem is that the multi select let me check\uncheck object with the same key. in the first time the objcet is key,x. removint the x make it stay with x,y(because I did not remove the y) then when pressing again on x,w I will have x twice. do you understand? (I added picture to the question)

Answer (score 0):

About your code

You has an `*ngIf =condition` and futhermore `[ngClass]=`the same condition?'':'display-none'`. So you can remove the [ngClass] -allways is fullfilled

You are using the event `(onChange)` to give value to the variables `selectedReasons` and `_decision.reasons`. See that the event.value is an array with all the object selected in the multi-select.

You already has `[(ngModel)]="selectedReasons"`, so is unnecesary use the event onChange

You has a formControlName="remark". I can not see your FormGroup. futhermore, you can **not** use in the same tag formControlName and ngModel. Maybe do you want use the event onChange to make some like:

```
onChangeReasonsValue(event: { value: ReviewDecisionReasonModel[] }): void {
    this.formGroup.get('mark'.setValue(event.value)
}
```

?
(but remember remove the formControlName in you code)

Sorry, I can not understand the `[required]="formGroup.hasError('remark-reasons-required')"`

Comment: First, Thank you very mush for your answer, I will try to focus my question, I tried what you wrote but it did not solve it because the problem is not display problem. I removed the ngModel. what happens it I have list of option for multi-select. in one off the option I should add another field-remark field. so selecting in the first time add this field. but when removing the selection it does not removing this selection from the array becouse I did not remove the remark field.

Comment: so when select this option again will add twice the same index(one with the remark field and one with null in the remark) I need to setvalue only if I dont have this index in the array